# Skype can't hear me

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, skype, microphone

This is driving me crazy. My friends can't hear my voice when I make a call using Skype. Here's the scenario:

1. Windows Sound Recorder correctly records my voice and I can hear my voice when I playback these recorded files.
2. In Windows Audio Settings, I see 3 devices on Recordings page: Microphone, Rear Input and Stereo Mix. Microphone is currently selected and the green bar moves as I speak into the mic. It is set as Default device and Default Communication device as well.
3. Skype appears to adjust microphone volume level as I speak loudly or quietly, but the green bar never moves.
4. Skype call testing service doesn't playback what I say.
5. I have tried it with front panel as well as rear input with the same results.
6. Microsoft Fix It for Skype audio problems didn't detect any issues.

Don't know what else to try. This is Win7 (64-bit) with the latest Skype. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It has been a while since I used Skype (and this is from memory) but it used to have its own built in option to use a different recording device

Comment: Correct, but I have Microphone selected there as well. The volume level bar moves only when this device is selected in Skype.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very strange issue, I think your best bet it to reset Skype

> Exit Skype : From the system tray >> right click on the skype icon and click "Quit Skype"
>
> Click Start >> Run Type: %appdata% Rename folder "Skype" to "Old_Skype"
>
> Re-run Skype
>
> Note: You will need your password to re-log on, and re-set any options from default

[Source](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/Skype-auto-logs-off/m-p/938210/highlight/true#M69026)

If that doesn't fix it then I guess it could be a driver issue (or a sound card conflict or similar)... Install ManyCam and see if that works (or not).